# MediatR generic handlers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-6.0, mediatr

I use a MediatR library in my Asp .Net core 6 app. And I have a the same logic for a group of requests, so I want to use the same handler for all of them. The problem is not new, but the solutions that I found did not help me. I have my own solution to solve this problem, but I do not like it and hope somebody knows a better way to solve this problem.

The example is shown here:

```
public class HandlerRequest<T> : IRequest
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
}

public class Handler<T> : IRequestHandler<HandlerRequest<T>>
{
    public Task<Unit> Handle(HandlerRequest<T> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // the logic is here
        return Task.FromResult(new Unit());
    }
}
```

The registration of MediatR is as follows:

```
builder.Services.AddMediatR(typeof(BusinessLayer));
```

When I try to call my mediatr for example:

```
await _mediator.Send(new HandlerRequest<int>{Data = 5});
await _mediator.Send(new HandlerRequest<string>{Data = "TEST"});
```

I get an exception:

> Error constructing handler for request of type
> MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[AT.Messenger.Credentials.Business.Requests.V1.Modeles.HandlerRequest`1[System.Int32],MediatR.Unit].
> Register your handlers with the container. See the samples in GitHub
> for examples.

The problem happens because MediatR can not register generic handler. I also tried to register handler as scoped or singleton service as I've seen that advice on the internet, but it does not help.

The only solution that I found - is inherit a new class from my handler:

```
public class HandlerInt : Handler<int>
{
}

public class HandlerString : Handler<string>
{
}
```

If use this approach, all works, but I don't like this solution. If anybody know better way to solve this problem give me an advice please.

Comment: This sounds similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60118890/imediatr-generic-request-handler-for-generic-requests?rq=1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have the following options, first, register what you will need explicitly like this.

```
services.AddTransient<IRequestHandler<HandlerRequest<int>, Unit>>, Handler<int>>();
//so on and so forth
```

This way you have registered the handlers for known types.

If you have open-bound generic, you can look into my [PR](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/pull/115) that gives you a

```
services.RegisterGenericMediatRHandlers(typeof(GenericHandlerBase).Assembly);
```

to automatically register classes inheriting from the constrained interface by using the method provided above.

Lastly, you can opt to use Autofac and register all your handlers like this:

```
        var mediatrOpenTypes = new[]
        {
                typeof(IRequestHandler<,>),
                typeof(IRequestExceptionHandler<,,>),
                typeof(IRequestExceptionAction<,>),
                typeof(INotificationHandler<>),
        };

        foreach (var mediatrOpenType in mediatrOpenTypes)
        {
            builder
                .RegisterAssemblyTypes(_assemblies.ToArray())
                .AsClosedTypesOf(mediatrOpenType)
                .AsImplementedInterfaces();
        }

//also by simply
  //builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Handler<>)).AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

This will also register all the generic handlers and you won't even have to register it explicitly inside the DI.

*btw*
The method you used to handle generic registration is the way described in the docs, to quote

> If you have an open generic not listed above, you'll need to register it explicitly. For example, if you have an open generic request handler, register the open generic types explicitly:

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>), typeof(GenericHandlerBase<,>));
```

> This won't work with generic constraints, so you're better off creating an abstract base class and concrete closed generic classes that fill in the right types.

Source: [docs link](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection)

Comment: This one 
services.AddTransient<IRequestHandler<HandlerRequest<int>, Unit>>, Handler<int>>(); 
works thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have colleted a lot of information and figured out a solution to register any kind of generic Mediator Handlers.

I was stuck trying to register one generic implementation with another generic class inside INotificationHandler, like this:

```
public class DomainEventsDispatcher<TEvent> : INotificationHandler<DomainEventDispatch<TEvent>> where TEvent : DomainEvent
```

PS: I'll use the example above to explain below.

Obviously, your cannot simply use "services.AddMediatr(typeof(AppAssembly))" because using Mediator with generic types, Handlers are not loaded into DI on startup.

So, I decided to register each implementation of each type of TEvent, however, I did it by looping the assemblies that implemented TEvent type and building each part to be used on services.AddTransient.

1. Looking for assemblies that implemented TEvent type;
2. First variable: Build the generic used inside INotificationHandler;
3. Second variable: Build the INotificationHandler with first variable;
4. Third variable: Build the generic implementation with TEvent type;
5. Returing the list ready to be injected;

Here is an extension I did to loop and build necessary types to register on DI:

```
public static class AssemblyExtensions
{
    public static List<(Type notificationHandler, Type implementation)> GetGenericNotificationHandlerForTypesOf(this Assembly assembly,
            Type AbstractClassToFilter, Type GenericUsedWithNotificationHandler, Type ImplementationType, Type NotificationHandlerGeneric)
    {
        List<(Type, Type)> list = new List<(Type, Type)>();

        foreach (Type item in from t in assembly.GetTypes()
                              where !t.IsAbstract && !t.IsInterface && t.BaseType == AbstractClassToFilter
                              select t)
        {
            var genericForNotificationHandler = GenericUsedWithNotificationHandler.MakeGenericType(item);
            var notificationHandler = NotificationHandlerGeneric.MakeGenericType(genericForNotificationHandler);
            var implementation = ImplementationType.MakeGenericType(item);

            list.Add((notificationHandler, implementation));
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Here is how to use (please take a look in the first example to understand the code below):

```
var registerPairs = typeof(DomainEvent).Assembly.GetGenericNotificationHandlerForTypesOf(typeof(DomainEvent), typeof(DomainEventDispatch<>), typeof(DomainEventsDispatcher<>), typeof(INotificationHandler<>));

registerPairs.ForEach(pair => services.AddTransient(pair.notificationHandler, pair.implementation));
```